# telnet inline with perl?

Tags: perl, telnet

Is there a way to allow perl to initiate a telnet session and programmatically issue commands to that telnet session?

I initially tried a stupid method:

commands.pl:

```
sleep(1);
print $command1;
sleep(1);
print $command2;
```

and then

```
> perl commands.pl | telnet www.host.com port
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Telnet) module.

```
use Net::Telnet ();
$t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 10,
                      Prompt => '/bash\$ $/');
$t->open("sparky");
$t->login($username, $passwd);
@lines = $t->cmd("who");
print @lines;
```

(Example taken from that page.)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be through [Perl's interface to Expect](http://p3rl.org/Expect).